# extract text from indented text file using ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

Using Ruta, I'm trying to extract data from text file. I have tried few approaches but not able to get exact required information. I need to fetch Borrower Name from indented text file.

Example:

```
Borrower Name: Alice                             SSN: 000-00-000  
Co-Borrower Name:                                SSN:
```

I annotated Borrower Name keyword and SSN keyword but not able to figure out query to get name.

```
Document{->RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};
DECLARE BorrowerKeyword, NameKeyword, BorrowerNameKeyword;
W{REGEXP("Borrower")->BorrowerKeyword};
W{REGEXP("Name")->NameKeyword};

(SPACE BorrowerKeyword SPACE NameKeyword){-> BorrowerNameKeyword};

DECLARE SSNKeyword;
W{REGEXP("SSN")->SSNKeyword};
DECLARE BorrowerNameLine;
Line{CONTAINS(BorrowerNameKeyword,10,100),
     CONTAINS(SSNKeyword,10,50)-> MARK(BorrowerNameLine)}; // Not able to annotate BorrowerNameLine


// other way but that also didn't work.
DECLARE BorrowerName;
RETAINTYPE(SPACE);
CW.ct=="Borrower" CW.ct=="Name" COLON n:W{-> CREATE(BorrowerName, "label"="Borrower Name", "value"=n.ct)};
RETAINTYPE;
```

Please suggest what I have missed and correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter the `SPACE` out after usage to avoid any undesired effects and to ease the rule development.

```
REMOVERETAINTYPE(SPACE);
DECLARE Borrower, Name; 
CW{REGEXP("\\bBorrower") -> Borrower} CW{REGEXP("Name") -> Name};
Borrower Name COLON n:W{-> CREATE(BorrowerName, "label"="Borrower Name", "value"=n.ct)};
```

Comment: Do I need to put Borrower Name in inverted commas? `"Borrower Name" COLON n:W{-> CREATE(BorrowerName, "label"="Borrower Name", "value"=n.ct)};` Otherwise it says `Borrower/Name is not defined in this script/block`

Comment: No, I assumed `Borrower` and `Name` to be pre-existing  annotations. See the adjusted rule block above.

Comment: What changes I have to incorporate if `Borrower Name : Alice Johnson ` Borrower Name consists of firstname, middlename and lastname

Comment: I am new to this, might seem naive question but why u have escape sequence "\b" Borrower regex? I think to not annotate Co-Borrower with Borrower tag

Comment: `Borrower Name COLON n:CW[1,3]{-> CREATE(BorrowerName, "label"="Borrower Name", "value"=n.ct)};`  if name comprises of firstname , middlename and lastname

Comment: If you want to save additional info to BorrowerName, you could declare them as features: `DECLARE BorrowerName (STRING firstName, STRING middleName, STRING lastName)` and then assign them accordingly as you did above for `value` and `label`.

Comment: Yes, the `\b` is used to match only on Borrower and not Co-Borrower. It sets the word boundaries.

Comment: Btw. if this solves your original problem, please don't forget to mark it as *Solution*